# JavaScript register an event type on several elements in one go

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, accessibility

Is there a way (natvie JS or JQuery) to register the same event type on a list of elements?

If possible I want to avoid the repetition of registering an event on several elements, one at a time.

Ideal (pseudo) code:

```
$({elem1, elem2, elem3}).on("keyup", function() {
    // Do the same when each one of these elements gets focus
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jQuery:

For cached element references you can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(elem1).add(elem2).add(elem3).on("keyup", function() {
    // Do the same when each one of these elements gets focus
});
```

Or, to select multiple elements by classname etc:

```
$(".one, .two, .three").on("keyup", function() {
    // Do the same when each one of these elements gets focus
});
```

If you have a dynamic array of cached element references:

```
var cache = [elem1, elem2, elem3]; // could be any length, added to dynamically etc...

var $collection = $(); // new empty jQuery object

// add each item to the jQuery object
for(var i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
    $collection = $collection.add(cache[i]);
}

$collection.on("keyup", function() {
    // Do the same when each one of these elements gets focus
});
```

Comment: The same works with native JS as well: `document.querySelectorAll("div, a")`

Comment: Also it's common practice to mark such elements with some CSS class and then access them like `$('li.user-record').on('keyup', onUserRecordKeyUp);`.

Comment: add() method doesn't modify referenced collection, you need: `$collection = $collection.add(cache[i]);` and you don't need to exclude cache[0] from loop, just set $collection as an empty jq object: `$()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
$("#id1, .class2, #id3").on("keyup", function() {
    //code
});
```